# gzip file is same as file size

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx, gzip

```
file    size    gzip size     file
js      217.4K  217.4K        js/scripts-0004.min.js
css     53.3K   53.3K         css/style-0004.min.css
```

why does `gzip` return files with the same size?

do they need additional packages for `gzip` on `ubuntu 12.04 + python + nginx server`.

nginx.conf

http {

```
##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

}

```
>>> r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('/style-0004.min.css', ... headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip;q=1.0, *;q=0'})) 
>>> print r.info() 
Server: nginx/1.1.19 Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2012 11:21:53 GMT 
Content-Type: text/css 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked Connection: close Vary: Accept-Encoding 
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT 
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1 
Content-Encoding: gzip 
>>> s = r.read() 
>>> print("comressed size: %d" % len(s)) 
comressed size: 12231 
>>> f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(s)) 
>>> print("uncompressed: %d" % len(f.read())) 
uncompressed: 53337

js file. comressed size: 63975 uncompressed: 217473
```

Comment: Why do you believe that those results are accurate? And where are they coming from?

Comment: Have you disabled compression by any chance: http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I used the YSlow plugin to check the size of the gzip files. the files from my server are not compressed where as other files from google and facebook have reduced size.

Comment: @Himanshu i do not compress from a python script. I use nginx to compress if the client browser supports gzip.

Comment: what is `r = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('http://nginxhost/js/scripts-0004.min.js', headers={'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip;q=1.0, *;q=0'})); print r.info(), len(r.read())`? See [example](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/4275149/)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian amazing! i get the compressed file. So the server is returning gzipped files. But why doesn't it compress when i send a request from my browser? The other files which i am requesting from google, facebook are compressed.

Comment: don't put info in the comments. [edit] your question instead. Inspect what headers your browser sends/receives e.g., you could use Wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with my current browser. Chromium for ubuntu 12.04.
I tried checking the gzipped files on mozilla firefox and i received the compressed files.

But I could not figure out why its happening with this browser because it fetches compressed files from other domains like facebook, google. and not mine!

Comment: you could compare http headers send by chromium and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

It might mean that the files are stored in the gzip archive uncompressed (`compresslevel == 0`) or you might have used `gzipfile.size` attribute that stores the original (uncompressed) data size.

Comment: files are gzipped on demand by nginx if the client browser supports accepting gzipped contents. compression level is 6. check nginx.conf in question